# django export csv issue while reading foreignkey field

Tags: python, django

here is my models.py

```
class RegistrationOTP(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='otp_country', default=1)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13)#, unique=True, validators=[phone_regex],
    otp = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_verified = models.CharField(choices=YES_OR_NO, default='no', max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s : %s'% (self.phone_number, self.otp)

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    phone_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

here is my admin.py

```
class RegistrationOTPResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
    model = RegistrationOTP
    fields = ('id','phone_number','otp','created_date','is_verified','country')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
    rep = super(RegistrationOTPResource, self).to_representation(instance)
    rep['country'] = instance.country.name
    return rep

class RegistrationOTPAdmin(ExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = RegistrationOTPResource

admin.site.register(RegistrationOTP, RegistrationOTPAdmin)


id  country phone_number    otp created_date    is_verified
151 1   6800000000  289320  2018-09-06 10:50:27 yes
150 1   9586773322  660144  2018-09-06 10:50:02 yes
149 1   9653694645  846690  2018-09-06 10:45:23 yes
148 1   6800000000  224465  2018-09-06 10:43:40 yes
147 1   6800000000  386181  2018-09-06 10:41:57 yes
146 1   919829621000    882178  2018-08-21 13:04:39 no
145 1   7584858585  446125  2018-08-21 13:04:39 no
144 1   6112355184  411237  2018-08-21 12:59:31 no
143 1   919829621000    434132  2018-08-21 12:59:25 no
142 1   7584858585  281552  2018-08-21 12:59:25 no
141 1   6112355184  757004  2018-08-21 12:57:38 no
```

In my csv country field is showing country id instead of country name. how can i show country name..

please have a look into my code

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super(RegistrationOTPResource, self).get_queryset(request).select_related('country')
```